# ScintillaNET lexer (XML) not functioning properly

Tags: xml, lexer, scintilla

I'm trying to get a lexer up for some gcode files I'm working with.  The lexer information for Scintilla has been sparse to say the least.  To date, all I've done is copy and paste the XML lexer and rename it as a gcode lexer.  The XML version runs fine, but the gcode lexer doesn't do ANYTHING.  Might anyone be able to help me out?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScintillaNET>
    <Language Name="gcode">

        <!-- 
            This is a bit of a hack that I picked up from SciTE, We keep the Stream 
            Comments as HTML Style and the Line Comments JavaScript Style. The better
            way to do it would be to change the comment strings whenever the selection
            changes based on if the current style is HTML or JavaScript (or VBScript,
            PHP, etc)           
         -->
        <Lexer LineCommentPrefix="//" StreamCommentPrefix="&lt;!-- " StreamCommentSuffix=" --&gt;" />


        <!-- 
            Additionally the HTML comment scheme lends itself better to having CTRL+Q toggle
            Line comments and CTRL+SHIFT+Q add Stream comments rather than having VS style
            comments.           
        -->
        <Commands Inherit="True">
            <Binding Key="Q" Modifier="Control" Command="ToggleLineComment" ReplaceCurrent="True"/>
            <Binding Key="Q" Modifier="Shift Control" Command="StreamComment" ReplaceCurrent="True"/>
        </Commands>

        <!-- 
            I saved the best for last. Styles, yeck. This is why the HTML config
            is so damned complicated.

            In order for any of the SubLangage Styles to inherit from the default config
            they have to be declared here even if they don't have any values set.
        -->
        <Styles Inherit="True">

            <!--
                As sort of a neat side-effect of how the SubLanguage inheritance works
                any styles declared here will be inherited by the sublanguage styles.
                Note that they have to be decalared before any of the sublanguages for
                it to work.
            -->

            <Style Name="DOUBLESTRING" ForeColor="Orchid" />
            <Style Name="SINGLESTRING" ForeColor="Orchid" />

            <SubLanguage Name="HTML">
                <Style Name="DEFAULT" />
                <Style Name="TAG" />
                <Style Name="TAGUNKNOWN" />
                <Style Name="ATTRIBUTE" />
                <Style Name="ATTRIBUTEUNKNOWN" />
                <Style Name="NUMBER" />
                <Style Name="DOUBLESTRING"  />
                <Style Name="SINGLESTRING"  />
                <Style Name="OTHER" />
                <Style Name="COMMENT" />
                <Style Name="ENTITY" />
                <Style Name="TAGEND" />
                <Style Name="XMLSTART" />
                <Style Name="XMLEND" />
                <Style Name="SCRIPT" />
                <Style Name="ASP" />
                <Style Name="ASPAT" />
                <Style Name="CDATA" />
                <Style Name="QUESTION" />
                <Style Name="VALUE" />
                <Style Name="XCCOMMENT" />
            </SubLanguage>

        </Styles>
    </Language>
</ScintillaNET>




    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScintillaNET>
    <Language Name="xml">

        <!-- 
            This is a bit of a hack that I picked up from SciTE, We keep the Stream 
            Comments as HTML Style and the Line Comments JavaScript Style. The better
            way to do it would be to change the comment strings whenever the selection
            changes based on if the current style is HTML or JavaScript (or VBScript,
            PHP, etc)           
         -->
        <Lexer LineCommentPrefix="//" StreamCommentPrefix="&lt;!-- " StreamCommentSuffix=" --&gt;" />


        <!-- 
            Additionally the HTML comment scheme lends itself better to having CTRL+Q toggle
            Line comments and CTRL+SHIFT+Q add Stream comments rather than having VS style
            comments.           
        -->
        <Commands Inherit="True">
            <Binding Key="Q" Modifier="Control" Command="ToggleLineComment" ReplaceCurrent="True"/>
            <Binding Key="Q" Modifier="Shift Control" Command="StreamComment" ReplaceCurrent="True"/>
        </Commands>

        <!-- 
            I saved the best for last. Styles, yeck. This is why the HTML config
            is so damned complicated.

            In order for any of the SubLangage Styles to inherit from the default config
            they have to be declared here even if they don't have any values set.
        -->
        <Styles Inherit="True">

            <!--
                As sort of a neat side-effect of how the SubLanguage inheritance works
                any styles declared here will be inherited by the sublanguage styles.
                Note that they have to be decalared before any of the sublanguages for
                it to work.
            -->

            <Style Name="DOUBLESTRING" ForeColor="Orchid" />
            <Style Name="SINGLESTRING" ForeColor="Orchid" />

            <SubLanguage Name="HTML">
                <Style Name="DEFAULT" />
                <Style Name="TAG" />
                <Style Name="TAGUNKNOWN" />
                <Style Name="ATTRIBUTE" />
                <Style Name="ATTRIBUTEUNKNOWN" />
                <Style Name="NUMBER" />
                <Style Name="DOUBLESTRING"  />
                <Style Name="SINGLESTRING"  />
                <Style Name="OTHER" />
                <Style Name="COMMENT" />
                <Style Name="ENTITY" />
                <Style Name="TAGEND" />
                <Style Name="XMLSTART" />
                <Style Name="XMLEND" />
                <Style Name="SCRIPT" />
                <Style Name="ASP" />
                <Style Name="ASPAT" />
                <Style Name="CDATA" />
                <Style Name="QUESTION" />
                <Style Name="VALUE" />
                <Style Name="XCCOMMENT" />
            </SubLanguage>

        </Styles>
    </Language>
</ScintillaNET>
```